# UB16.1 Cant run gcc compiled program file

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run a programm written in c that uses gtk and l bluetooth, from a fresh install of Ubuntu  16.1     When I do  `./bluedialog2`    from the terminal I get the message

```
bash: ./bluedialog2: No such file or directory
```

and when I do   `$ ls`   I get

```
willio@willio-HP-Notebook:~$ ls
bluedialog2  Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
Desktop      Downloads  Music             Public    Videos
```

And when I copy and paste   `bluedialog2` into the command line from the listed files, I get the original message.
What can I do to run my programs and widgets.

Thanks.

edit1
     After running the command `file ./bluedialog2 it returned`

```
$ file ./bluedialog2
./bluedialog2: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=51a106bab5ccc88a5f479428b2621cf9de72c3a4, not stripped
```

Comment: Run `ldd ./bluedialog2` and install missing libraries

Comment: @ muru   Thanks I ran the command you gave and it returned    not a dynamic executable    What does that mean ?  I will install gtk and bluetooth and see what happens

Comment: In that case, add the output of `file ./bluedialog2` to your question.

Comment: Is it because its a 32 bit exe  being run on a 64 bit os.  If I recompile them on this new one will they work.

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Or alternatively you add support for 32-bit programs.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am having some issues with the compiling, so a cant say 100% anything but at this point I m pretty convinced about what happened and thanks for the options.